# Missing modules Pyinstaller

Tags: python

I have been trying to convert a .py to .exe using pyinstaller and as you can see from the title..  the .exe file does not execute properly.. it says it does not find the module (numpy). So I did some research and I discovered that pyinstaller can have difficulties in finding modules..
Pyinstaller website:

pyi-makespec --paths=/path/to/thisdir \
             --paths=/path/to/otherdir myscript.py

The code above would help pyinstaller finding them. My questions are:
In what directory are my libraries? (such as numpy, pandas, etc)
Would this be a different code? or would I add this into my code? or would this go somewhere in this line 'pyinstaller myscript.py' ???
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

im 99.9999% sure that pyinstaller already has hooks for numpy

just add `import numpy` at the top of `myscript.py`

and run `pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py && .\dist\myscript.exe`

but to answer your question look in the site-packages folder of you python folder (type `which python` to find your python version) or `which pyinstaller` to see your pyinstaller location (it should be the same as `which python` but in the scripts folder)

it used to be located at C:\PythonX.Y\Lib\

in 3.X it is usually located in your AppData folder

Comment: I ran what you told me to and it wokred with numpy, unfortunately all the modules that I have to import are the ones below. now it's says it does not find pandas. :-import numpy as np
-import pandas as pd
-from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
-from sqlalchemy import create_engine
-import json
-import sys, getopt