# Pyinstaller python 3.8 missing module named

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pyinstaller

When I use PyInstaller to create myfile.exe from myfile.py in warn-myfile lots of "missing module named", "excluded module named"errors pop up.

I have:
PyInstaller 4.0
Python 3.8.5

Example:

```
missing module named 'win32com.gen_py' - imported by win32com (conditional, optional), ...\venv\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py (top-level)

missing module named 'usb.backend.libusb01' - imported by ...\venv\Lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_usb.py (optional)

missing module named psutil._psutil_aix - imported by psutil (top-level), psutil._psaix (top-level)

missing module named psutil._psutil_sunos - imported by psutil (top-level), psutil._pssunos (top-level)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing modules Pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48835956/missing-modules-pyinstaller)

Comment: Or any of these: https://www.google.com/search?q=pyinstaller+missing+module

Comment: Probably I checked most of the advice people gave under the given questions and still nothing

Answer (score 0):

OK I found how to avoid libusb error
`missing module named 'usb.backend.libusb01' - imported by ...\venv\Lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_usb.py (optional)`

https://blog.csdn.net/qq_39718408/article/details/105429980

```
binaries = [
(‘C:\Windows\System32\libusb-1.0.dll’, ‘.’),
]
a = Analysis([‘pyusb.py’],
pathex=[‘F:\mywork\python_util’],
binaries=binaries,
datas=[],
hiddenimports=[‘usb’],
…
```

Probably it works